# <main> tag vs <div class=container> tag

Tags: html, sublimetext

I am currently building a site using only HTML5 tags (ie no `div` tags). I am working on styling the `main` tag for my container, however CSS isn't targeting `main` tag in Sublime as an appropriate tag.

[image: Screenshot of CSS file in Sublime]

Comment: is there a question hidden somewhere?

Comment: he's asking why "main"didn't get sublime's syntax highlighting. hence the screenshot. although, this is really just a question about sublime and maybe doesn't belong here

Comment: I understand divs are legal, this was an assignment for a course (not to use div tags).

Is there any reason why Sublime wouldn't recognize the main tag?

Answer (score 2):

In sublime by default, html 5 isn't recognized. You have to install package control:

https://packagecontrol.io/

After this you have to install HTML 5 bundle:

https://packagecontrol.io/search/html%205

Comment: Followed the istructions but nothing :( thanks though

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the response but, for me works like a charms. Sublime 2 or 3? the doctype is correct? https://monosnap.com/file/qPY7nrqSCnM4jOaQhWjTQTJiZnL1eB

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is targeting your main tag, and the CSS is being applied, however for some reason Sublime doesn't colorize the 'main' selector in the CSS file. It does the same thing in my Sublime 3 application. You can test this is working by doing:

```
main {background-color: red;}
```

Or whatever color is more appropriate. Save the file, refresh your local page and you should see this change has taken effect.